# In a Slurm cluster job, how can AveCPU time be greater than CPUTime?

Tags: multiprocessing, slurm

```
       JobID    JobName     MaxRSS    Elapsed     AveCPU    CPUTime  SystemCPU 
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- 
16260894             GP              06:29:33            2-16:55:30   05:49:13 
16260894.ba+      batch      3336K   06:29:33   00:00:00 2-16:55:30  00:00.008 
16260894.0   gp_wrappe+   5566876K   06:29:33 3-11:40:54 2-16:55:30   05:49:13
```

Above is the `sacct` output for a job I ran on a slurm cluster. I used 10 CPU, 1 task and 1 node. I'm still not too familiar with using slurm clusters, but here's what I think I understand: `CPUTime` represents the max amount of cpu time the jobs could have taken, and in this case is just equal to `n_cpus * Elapsed`. However, my thought was that `AveCPU` was the actual cpu time used in the program.

Not only would I expect it to be less than `CPUTime` in principle, because I can't use more resources than I have. But also, I would expect my script to only be using the max processing power (all 10 cores) a fraction of the time since only some parts of the processing are fully multithreaded. So how can it be that `AveCPU` is 3.5 days, while `CPUTime` is 2.7 days?